# What is the correct syntax to make them work together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am still getting a hang of react+redux, and ES6. I am trying to implement i18n, and I come across the problem of having to export i18n translate with my redux's connect.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(UserList);

export default translate("translations")(UserList);
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) *"I come across the problem of having to export i18n translate with my redux's connect"* What is the problem, specifically?

Comment: I am having this in my component                                                                    export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(UserList);            and want to add this also                                                                                                            export default translate("translations")(UserList);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
export default translate("translations")(connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(UserList));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not particularly clear. My understanding is that you are trying to use i18n and redux together. You need to use Compose to stitch them together.

```
import { ..., compose } from 'redux'

compose(
  connect(...),
  translate("translations")
)(MyComponent)
```

https://redux.js.org/api/compose

Answer (score 0):

I think you only `export default` once. And you can `export` multiple functions. For example, `export function Example(){}`

Answer (score 0):

version 1:

```
export default translate('translations')(connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps))(UserList)
```

version 2:
(But iam not sure if lodash compose is still a thing)
import { compose } from 'lodash';

```
export default compose(
  translate('translations'),
  connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps),
)(UserList);
```

you mightbe also interested in packages like [recompse](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose.)